# How to remove variables from links on a page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Simply I have a bunch of links like so

```
<div id="categoryLinks">
    <a href="blah.php?something=this&category=21"></a>
    <a href="blah.php?something=that&category=21"></a>
    <a href="blah.php?something=then&category=21"></a>
</div>
```

What I'd like to be able to do however, is go through all those links and remove the end bit '&category=21' should I choose to so they would all look like:

```
<div id="categoryLinks">
    <a href="blah.php?something=this"></a>
    <a href="blah.php?something=that"></a>
    <a href="blah.php?something=then"></a>
</div>
```

So I'm working on the function that looks something like this:

```
function removeCategory(){

    $('#categoryLinks a').each(function(){

        // as you can see, i don't know what goes in here!      

});


}
```

I know how to do the opposite, which is to append a category to the href, but as far as taking it off I am drawing a blank.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will strip all parameters

```
$('a[href*=?]').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href.substring(0, href.indexOf('?'));
});
```

This will strip particular one

```
$("a[href*='category=']").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href.replace(/&?category=\d+/, ''));
});
```

`a[href*='category=']` looks for an `category=` string in `href` attribute of `a` tag. Then this atrribute along with coresponding value is replaced with empty string.

Comment: good approach, especially with regards to regular expressions. 2 notes however - you should use quotes when selecting for attributes (or parts thereof) with characters like '=' and perhaps an explanation of how your code works would be good.

Comment: jQuery attribute selectors works well without quotes as well.

Comment: @cosmicbdog you don't know much about JS variables, do you?

Comment: ha. no, not really. Hey this is working a treat, but it seems on IE a user reported it not working. Does the above code have any compatibility issues with internet explorer?

Comment: It shouldn't have. Do you have more details on the issue?

Comment: Sorry to bother you man. I sorted it. It was my fault as usual.